# Infinite loop on 'getline' in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, infinite-loop, getline

I am working through some C++ exercises in Visual Studio 2010, and I keep having problems with an infinite loop which occurs when I try to terminate a standard in stream with "CTRL-Z", when using the `getline()` function. Here is the relevant bit of code....

```
// find all the lines that refer to each word in the input
map<string, vector<int> >
    xref(istream& in,
         vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split)
{
    string line;
    int line_number = 0;
    map<string, vector<int> > ret;

    // read the next line
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        // break the input line into words
        vector<string> words = find_words(line);

        // remember that each word occurs on the current line
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
             it != words.end(); ++it)
            ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

...instead of kicking me out of the while loop, the program goes into an infinite loop printing a random integer. I'm pretty sure this is something specific to the Windows environment that I'm missing. Here's the entire code...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "split.h"

using std::find_if;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

using std::isspace;

// `true' if the argument is whitespace, `false' otherwise
bool space(char c)
{
    return isspace(c);
}

// `false' if the argument is whitespace, `true' otherwise
bool not_space(char c)
{
    return !isspace(c);
}

vector<string> split(const string& str)
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    vector<string> ret;

    iter i = str.begin();
    while (i != str.end()) {

        // ignore leading blanks
        i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);

        // find end of next word
        iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);

        // copy the characters in `[i,' `j)'
        if (i != str.end())
            ret.push_back(string(i, j));
        i = j;
    }
    return ret;
}

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "split.h"

using std::cin;            using std::cout;
using std::endl;           using std::getline;
using std::istream;        using std::string;
using std::vector;         using std::map;

// find all the lines that refer to each word in the input
map<string, vector<int> >
    xref(istream& in,
         vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split)
{
    string line;
    int line_number = 0;
    map<string, vector<int> > ret;

    // read the next line
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        // break the input line into words
        vector<string> words = find_words(line);

        // remember that each word occurs on the current line
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin();
             it != words.end(); ++it)
            ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    // call `xref' using `split' by default
    map<string, vector<int> > ret = xref(cin);

    // write the results
    for (map<string, vector<int> >::const_iterator it = ret.begin();
         it != ret.end(); ++it) {
        // write the word
        cout << it->first << " occurs on line(s): ";

        // followed by one or more line numbers
        vector<int>::const_iterator line_it = it->second.begin();
        cout << *line_it;   // write the first line number

        ++line_it;
        // write the rest of the line numbers, if any
        while (line_it != it->second.end()) {
            cout << ", " << *line_it;
            ++line_it;
        }
        // write a new line to separate each word from the next
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since there's no printing code in your post, I'm tempted to assume that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Isn't Ctrl+D the EOF character?

Comment: I *think* Ctrl-D is for linux/unix, and Ctrl-z is for Windows.

Comment: My only guess is you are not typing Ctrl+z on its own line. What are you typing into the command prompt?

Comment: I'm typing alpha sentences into the command line, each terminated with Enter/'\n', and then Ctrl-z on it's own line.

Comment: I'd recommend to add a debug print near getline - before, inside and after the loop. It is to be sure that the problem is getline.

Comment: How do you evaluate the input stream as true or false?

Comment: This example is literally straight out of a book. In a Unix-like system, I *believe* an EOF character, i.e. Ctrl-C, will cause the input stream to evaluate as false. I took that to mean that in a windows environment Ctrl-z would cause the input stream to evaluate as false. But this isn't just C++ in the windows environment, it's "visual" C++, so I'm wondering if it's not some idiosyncrasy of that language, and I'm trying to figure out how to get this example to work with visual C++ in the Visual Studio 2010 environment.

Comment: So yeah, this is definitely something specific to Visual Studio. I tried the exact same code in another IDE that sits on top of the mingw implementation, and it worked fine. Any insight into what exactly is up would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of trying to make this work, I'd start by writing code I could understand (and for me to understand it, the code has to be fairly simple):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include "infix_iterator.h"

typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<unsigned> > index;

namespace std {
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, index::value_type const &i) { 
    os << i.first << ":\t";
    std::copy(i.second.begin(), i.second.end(),
        infix_ostream_iterator<unsigned>(os, ", "));
    return os;
}
}

void add_words(std::string const &line, size_t num, index &i) { 
    std::istringstream is(line);
    std::string temp;

    while (is >> temp)
        i[temp].push_back(num);
}

int main() { 
    index i;
    std::string line;
    size_t line_number = 0;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        add_words(line, ++line_number, i);

    std::copy(i.begin(), i.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<index::value_type>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

As (more or less) usual, this needs the `infix_ostream_iterator` I've posted [elsewhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13176/infix-iterator-code).